# About ActionPerformed and ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, actionevent

I still have not totally understood some java concepts like Listeners and Adapters, etc, and I recently was looking for a way to execute some code when I press enter while a JTextField has the focus and I found this code:

```
JTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Enter pressed");
    }
}
);
```

This code works fine but I have no clue of how does the JTextField knows that I want the code to be executed when I press the Enter key. I'm guessing that the JTextField has defined in its code for wich events (like Enter press) it will "answer". I hope someone can help me clarify this doubt

Comment: Look at here . https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Event_Handling . This site will give you basic information about Event handling.

Answer (score 2):

- `ENTER key` is implemented as `KeyBindings` (field accept) for `JFormattedTextField`, `JTextField`, `JPasswordField`
- this notifiers generated an event by invoking ActionListener (notifiers, methods in API), for a.m. `JComponent`s you can to listening this event by add `ActionListener`
- another `JComponent`s can firing even from `ENTER key` to two or more `AWT/Swing Listeners`, e.g. for `JComboBox` from `ActionListener` and `ItemListener`
- most of Swing `JComponent`s has implemented the common/standard accelators, similair as in MS Windows (MsOffice etc...), those key events are implemented as `KeyBindings` in Swing
- you can to add, change, block those events implemented in API. or add, define own key shortcuts by using  `KeyBindings`
- its about good practicies to use `KeyBindings` instead of `KeyListener` (bunch of Q&A here)

Comment: see [all Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) by @camickr

Answer (score 0):

In java GUIs listens (called  Listener) to Actions from user. There are a lot of listener that can be used for a specific GUI. For Textfield for example listens to actio events.  ActionEvent triggers a GUI that listens to that event, so whenever you clicked a focused GUI it respond.